# How to get Apple Sign-in to work in iOS 15 Simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

Is there a trick to get Apple Sign-In to work on the iOS 15 simulators? It works fine on the iOS 13 simulators, but for iOS 15 it just stays stuck on the modal view where it asks for your password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed on iOS 16 simulator. Update to latest iOS simulator.